# Only Allow POST Requests and Deny all other REQUEST_METHOD using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, web-applications, http-post, httpserver

I have some email PHP Scripts which I do not want the user to have a look by a GET, but I am using it to send as an email, using wufoo's webHook if anyone knows about it, so it uses POST so I just want POST Requests to be allowed otherwise, 403 or 404 how do I do that?

I tried some answers given on SO and browsed documentation of apache web server, the best answer I found was this:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=GET
 RewriteRule ^.*$ /path/to
```

But I suppose this should be written in the directory where I have PHP Script, I just want use one .htaccess in root.

Folder Structure :

```
      public_html (would want to use this folders .htaccess only)
      -- email 
         -- mail.php (ONLY POST)
```

I know we can use REQUEST_METHOD in `mail.php` directly but I don't want to do that, it is kind of thing which is not related to the script actually.

can anyone provide some help.

Comment: How about do it all in PHP.. redirect the page to 404 if any GET string exist? Easier to execute and less likely to break other scripts..

Comment: but suppose there are like 100 pages, I should not go to 100 pages and do that correct? I need one centralized file where I can manage all that, thats the reason for asking this question..

Comment: I've done this by throwing a custom exception that I call `PostMethodNotAllowed` in any page/script that requires POST. This exception is caught and the HTTP error headers (say 403) can be set in that exception handler along with a user-friendly message.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteRule .* - [R=405,L]
```

Comment: Although this code might answer the question, I recommend that you also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.