# How to completely ignore GET requests?

Tags: php

I have a php script which receives POST data as packets from my javascript aplication and processes it.

I'm having a problem where GET requests are being sent to it and interrupting the flow during runtime as it sends a blank response to my AJAX in my javascript. I haven't been able to track down the source of these requests despite a lot of effort, although they are coming from my IP.

How can I make my script completely ignore GET requests so ideally it doesn't even startup if a GET request is sent to it? (Not just die at the start if it's a get request which is what I have now).

Comment: if you only use, `$_POST`, then your problem will be solved :)... rather using `$_GET` or `$_REQUEST`

Comment: Duplicate?  See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12606290/only-allow-post-requests-and-deny-all-other-request-method-using-htaccess

Comment: I only use POST in the script, but the GET requests are starting the script during runtime and intefering with the responses sent back to my AJAX.

Comment: Something else is wrong with your script, php is a share nothing architecture, one request should not effect another. Please provide more details, blocking get requests is just a bad sticky plaster, not a solution

Comment: I have a javascript app that sends packets to the script as POST data. The script processes the data, sends a response back and the javascript sends the next packet. When the script receives a GET request mid processing a blank response goes back to the AJAX and interrupts the whole thing so it doesn't receive a response back from the original POST data so it doesn't send the next packet. I need to completely ignore GET requests to stop this as I can't find the source of the GET requests.

Comment: So what's the problem? Look at the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` and if its a `POST`, then process your data, otherwise send an error code

Comment: How is this different from just making the script die if the POST data sent to it is blank? (Which is what I'm currently doing)... with that the script dies if GET data is sent to it, but the fact that it started up at all means it sends a response back to my AJAX with interferes with sending packets.

Comment: @user2721465 its no different, and not a solution. As i said, one request should not effect another, the fantom get request should NOT effect the responce to the ajax post request, something else is wrong.

Comment: If you are determined to block get requests, see the post linked by @HaukurHaf - you block at the web server level, not php

Comment: @user574632 Absolutely, but I've posted in 4 forums and opened about 5 questions on here trying to find the solution to where these GET requests are coming from and nobody can figure it out so I need another solution. Thanks, I'll check out the block at server level method

Comment: Where the request is coming from is not the main problem, why its magically effecting another request is the problem. Are you using some kind of cache or other persistence? Or is it a case of time out due to increased serve load (seems unlikely from a single request)?

Comment: Yeah I can't figure it out. I used Chrome Restful Client to rule out problems with my javascript. It's not a timeout because the original script will continue running until the end, but a GET request is sent almost like clockwork about 1-2 minutes into the script running. This sends a response back to even the Restful Client. (btw not using cache... and I've managed to replicate this error by just having the most basic script which just counts up to 50 with 10 second pauses... still happens)

Comment: I believe it IS a timeout, on the client side, not the server - the browser is timing out and sending the get request with a connection:close header. Try setting a high timeout in your JS, if using jquery simply set `timeout:120000` (2 minutes). Also in the event of a timeout, the jquery error callback will fire, so log that to test. I think chrome rest client plugin has a fixed timeout that you cant change.

Comment: Ah ok, nice. I'll give that a go, cheers.

Comment: Ok I added timeout:120000 in the globals and still get the issue unfortunately before the timeout period (I already have jquery setup btw).

Answer (score 1):

> How can I make my script completely ignore GET requests so ideally it
>   doesn't even startup if a GET request is sent to it?

If so, then you need to ensure that request isn't `GET` before start doing another stuff.

```
if (strtoupper($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) === 'GET') {
  exit;
}

// Now do another stuff
```

P.S Be careful with overriding `$_GET` and another superglobals - this is because third-party libraries might use it (if you include a one in future)

Answer (score 0):

You could just override the values within the `$_GET` variable at the start of your script:

```
unset( $_GET );
```

With regard to these variables "interrupting the flow during runtime" - the only way for this to happen is if you are actually using or parsing these parameters. Simply ignore them in the code: ie - don't reference it.

Comment: I have a javascript app that sends packets to the script as POST data. The script processes the data, sends a response back and the javascript sends the next packet.

When the script receives a GET request mid processing a blank response goes back to the AJAX and interrupts the whole thing so it doesn't receive a response back from the original POST data so it doesn't send the next packet.

I need to completely ignore GET requests to stop this as I can't find the source of the GET requests.